# It is time we should accept

Tags: usage

Is the following sentence wrong?

> It is time we should accept all our people as equals and as partners in the task of building a strong and united nation.

My teacher says it is wrong but I am not able to identify the error. To me this sentence sounds correct.

Somebody help me.........

Comment: Did you ask your teacher why they think its wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two clauses:

It is time
we should accept ...

But you have no conjunction to link them together.  This is possible in some cases, such as some relative clauses:

> He is a man we met at work.

But this doesn't quite work here, the clause "we should..." doesn't describe time. A better way to express this is

> "It is time for us to accept...",

or else split into separate sentences (which is highly dramatic and may not be the style you want to achieve)

"It is time.  We should ..."

The use of "all our people" is a little odd. I think you mean "the people in our country" but I'm not sure. Perhaps "all people" or "each other", since "We" refers apparently to "people in the country".